# Getting credit_balance

Tags: facebook-credits, credits

I've got a whitelisted app for credits on FB and I'm trying to get the balance for a user but I keep getting error 13.  That credits_balance is not part of the user table.

The docs say to re-authenticate the user after being whitelisted and I believe I've done.

However, is their "authentication" just FB.login?  I read through the permissions page to see if there was a special permission I needed to ask for, but haven't had any luck.

I'm not sure what else they mean by authenticate users if it's not that.

Any info is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I requested for credits special incentives for my apps, and nothing happened for a while and I didn't have permissions to get user's balance.

I contact Facebook's support and listed my apps ids, and then they got me whitelisted and now I can access user's balance.

Are you sure you're whitelisted? How?

Comment: I'm whitelisted for another API call.  My contact at FB is checking to see if there's more than one list.